# Display dates based on month and year dropdown -php ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Hello i have the following code that will display dates based on dropdown of month and year

#### index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showDate() {

    var str=document.getElementById("mymonth").value;
    var str1=document.getElementById("myyear").value;
  if (str==0) {// if nothing is selected from first drop down
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
    return;
  } 
                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {
                    // code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
                    if (this.readyState==4 && this.status==200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=this.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getdate.php?selectedmonth="+str+"&selectedyear="+str1,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }

</script>
</head>
<body>


<form>
            <select name="mymonth" id="mymonth" onchange="showDate()">
 <option>Select Month</option>
      <option value="01">January</option>
      <option value="02">February</option>
      <option value="03">Mac</option>
      <option value="04">April</option>
      <option value="05">Mei</option>
      <option value="06">June</option>
      <option value="07">July</option>
      <option value="08">August</option>
      <option value="09">September</option>
      <option value="10">October</option>
      <option value="11">November</option>
      <option value="12">December</option>
      </select>
<select name="myyear" id="myyear" onchange="showDate()">
                <option>Select Year:</option>
                <option value="2016">2016</option>
                 <option value="2017">2017</option>
            </select>     



</form>

<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Date group by month/year</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

#### getdate.php

```
<?php
$selectedmonth = intval($_GET['selectedmonth']);
$selectedyear = intval($_GET['selectedyear']);

$month = "$selectedmonth";
$year = "$selectedyear";

$start_date = "01-".$month."-".$year;
$start_time = strtotime($start_date);

$end_time = strtotime("+1 month", $start_time);

echo "<table border='1'>";

for($i=$start_time; $i<$end_time; $i+=86400)
{
$list = date('d M Y (D)', $i);
echo "<tr><td>";
echo $list;
echo "</td>";

echo "<td>&nbsp;</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";


?>
```

### Questions:

1. How do i make it so only when both month and year are selected only then getdate.php will be display?

Right now when we select the month and year for first time it is showing incorrect result.

As example when we pick June it will display

> 31 May 2001 until 30 Jun 2001

and if we select `2016`, it will display `2015` dates.

After that when we select again, the month or year it will show correct result.:stars:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add value attribute to the default select option.

```
<option value="">Select Month</option>
<option value="">Select Year:</option>
```

Put the following condition before making Ajax request.

```
if(str == '' || str1 == ''){
    return;
}
//Your Ajax goes here...
```

Add the timezone to the PHP file, in the beginign of the file, below `<?php` open tag.

```
date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata"); //Change your timezone accordingly. Here it's set to Kolkatta, India.
```

I hope it helps you !